# Mysql : removing all occurences of a string in a field except first causing odd behaviour

Tags: mysql, replace, find-occurrences

I was looking for a way to let only one occurence of the same string in a field a fews days ago, and someone provided me with a really nice answer.
The idea was to turn a field like that :

```
 MyString OtherString MyString AnotherString AndAnother MyString
```

into

```
MyString OtherString AnotherString AndAnother
```

The solution I was given is this :

```
UPDATE 
MyTable 
SET 
MyField = 
CONCAT(
    LEFT(MyField,INSTR(MyField,'MyString') + LENGTH('MyString')), 
    REPLACE(RIGHT(MyField, LENGTH(MyField) - (INSTR(MyField,'MyString') + LENGTH('MyString'))), 'MyString','') 
)
```

While it does the job, it messes up in some fields, turning the 'MyString' into

```
'MyyyyyStrrrriing' or 'MyString ng ng', 'MyString ing' and so on(there's so many variations going on)
```

heck, even on another string in the field, such as :

```
OtheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerString

AndAnothertherthertherther
```

Any idea on how to perfect this solution even further ?

original question :
[MySQL : replace occurence of a string in field except first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110836/mysql-replace-occurence-of-a-string-in-field-except-first-one)

Comment: If you can write a script (php or pyton) it's can be better, fist you get all row and for every row you remove all occurrences than you update your table

Comment: oh my God. Thanks @ImaneZIABAT , sometimes it's there and obvious you can use one of the languages you know to help out, but you just don't even think about it

Comment: Actually when I find that my sql query will be more complicated automatically I move to a programming language (İt is fast and easy)